# Need help on Multi-threaded Programming with C on Linux

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads

I'm starting to learn about Multi-threaded Programming with C on Linux. Below are my exercise and my code for executing the hello function for each thread. Please show me what is wrong.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <pthread.h>
    
#define NUM_THREADS 4
     
void *hello(void * );
     
int main() {
  int j;
  pthread_t tid[NUM_THREADS];
     
  printf("My process ID %d\n", getpid());
  for (j = 0; j < NUM_THREADS; j++)
    pthread_create(&tid[j], NULL, hello, (void*)j); //original is pthread_create([1])
     
  for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++)
    pthread_join(tid[i], NULL); //original is pthread_join([2])
     
  return 0;
}
     
void *hello(void * my_id) {
  printf("Hello World from branch thread %d\n", *(int * ) my_id);
}
```

There are only two lines that can go wrong as below because it's a fill-in blank exercise, and the below two lines are I add. I think it's `(void*)j`

```c
    pthread_create(&tid[j], NULL, hello, (void*)j); //[1]
    pthread_join(tid[i], NULL); //[2]
```

[1] is creating child thread with tid, each child thread executes hello function with argument j.

[2] is main thread only ends when all child thread is ended

I don't have the expected output for this. But I have an expected output for the advanced request (which need to change some part of the original code, not only fill in [1] and [2]) as below:

```
My process ID 127

Hello World from branch thread 0

Hello World from branch thread 1

Hello World from branch thread 2

Hello World from branch thread 3
```

My error is:

```
quang@quang-VirtualBox:~$ gcc exe2_1.c -o exe2_1 -pthread
exe2_1.c: In function ‘main’:
exe2_1.c:32:42: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
   32 |     pthread_create(&tid[j], NULL, hello, (void*)j)
```

Please understand that my first subject was Python, this is my second subject (operating system), I have zero knowledge of C, but my school force me to learn this. I just need the fixed code so that I can submit.

Comment: Which part of these lines were blank? Casting an integer to a pointer type does not make it a pointer and you cannot dereference it.

Comment: What is expected output of that code? Shall each thread print the number that was stored in `j` when the thread was created? Is it OK if some or all threads print the same number?

Comment: @Gerhardh two blank part are pthread_create([1]) and pthread_join([2]). [1] is creating child thread with tid, each child thread executes hello function with argument j. [2] is main thread only ends when all child thread is ended.

Comment: I assume, `hello` function is fixed. Then the description of `[1]` is nonsense. You cannot pass `j` as argument but you can only pass the address of it as argument.

Comment: @Gerhardh I edited my question, all parameters in pthread_create and pthread_join are blank

Comment: Whatever you pass as last parameter, must match what `hello` expects to get. Would calling `hello(();` directly with `(void*)j` work? Probably not. Same for `pthread_create`. As a simple solution try `&j` instead. And watch the output...

Comment: @Gerhardh THANK YOU SO MUCH! IT WORKS!!. The output is "My process ID 2975" followed by 4 lines of "Hello World from branch thread 4". May I ask that my school have another advance request, which changes the code so that the expected output is "Hello World from branch thread 0" followed by "Hello World from branch thread 1" then 2 then 3. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not specify which output is expected. The solution would depend on the fact whether you expect to see the different number from each thread or if some threads may print the same number.

To fix the message from your compiler, you must provide a real pointer. Not just some integer that you cast to pointer.

If you do

```c
    int j = 1;
    pthread_create(&tid[j], NULL, hello, (void*)j);
```

this will result in `hello` being called with `1` which contains an integer value. But `hello` thinks, it is a pointer and tries to dereference it.
This will not work.

Instead you must provide the address of some `int` variable.
Changing the relevant line to

```c
    pthread_create(&tid[j], NULL, hello, &j);
```

would do the trick.

But... (as you commented in the meantime)

You noticed that all threads print the same number if you do this.
That happens because you pass the same address of same variable to each thread.
And there is no specific order when the threads are executed.
Chances are good that the first thread is executed after the whole loop was done.
To avoid this, you must provide each thread with a different value.
You cannot do this by just adding parameters to that function call.
Instead you must provide separate memory for each thread.
You could do this as follows:

```c
  int params[NUM_THREADS];
  for (j = 0; j < NUM_THREADS; j++)
  {
    params[j] = j;
    pthread_create(&tid[j], NULL, hello, &params[j]);
  }
```

This will cause each thread to print a different number.

Comment: Thank you it works now. I don't understand much since I don't learn C. I will research more about this to understand your explanation. But now I can submit the exercise. Thanks!

Comment: Alternatively, you can use the standard integer pointer-storage types (ex: `intptr_t`) to convey the id by value, and thus avoid the 'id' array. [See here](https://godbolt.org/z/6Wzfr9xv6).

Comment: @WhozCraig as far as I understand, the thread function was provided. Your suggestion cannot be done using the given function.

Comment: @Gerhardh Oh sorry one more question. There is no way to force the code to print 0 1 2 3 right? You can force the number to be different but you can force it to show in order?

Comment: That is a very different thing and you should ask a new question for that.

Comment: @Gerhardh absolutely. love to run into the author of that thread function regardless, since it is flat lying about its promise to return a `void *` (it returns nothing). My point was not to answer the fill-in-the-blank nonsense. it was to convey that one can do this, should they desire, without having to stand up an otherwise-unused sequence. It was to point out that if conveying a value to a thread function is all that is desired, it can be done a number of ways, depending on how you wish to arrange the startup and the function itself.  that's all.

Comment: @WhozCraig Those strange tasks are always a bit like tying one arm on your back and only allowing to walk sideways...

Answer (score 0):

Very simple you have over complicated the passing of the parameter j you just need to  pass its address using the &

Syntax is

```
int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, pthread_attr_t *attr,
                   void *(*start_routine) (void *arg), void *arg);
```

Passing to a function

```
void *thread(void *arg)
```

Your line should read

```
pthread_create(&tid[j], NULL, hello, &j);
```

Output expected for your exercise

```
Hello World from branch thread 1
Hello World from branch thread 2
Hello World from branch thread 3
Hello World from branch thread 4
```

Comment: But somehow the number after the thread is random (not 1 2 3 4), sometimes it's 3 3 4 4, 4 4 4 4, 3 4 4 4. May I ask why?

Comment: Oh I have the answer in the below answer "There is no specific order when the threads are executed. Chances are good that the first thread is executed after the whole loop was done. To avoid this, you must provide each thread with a different value. You cannot do this by just adding parameters to that function call. Instead you must provide separate memory for each thread."

Comment: I would note that if you do by any chance go into  programming learning this early is an advantage in modern multithreaded systems, I wish I had the opportunity to learn this 30 odd years ago when I first started.

Comment: Thank you. Surely if I have free time I will research more about this multi-threading programming